# Change colour of random textboxes C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 text boxes all with white backgrounds. When the application is run I want the following to take place:

1. A randomly selected text box should change to red
2. When the user moves the mouse over that box, it should change back to white
3. Repeat

When I put a loop in it makes all 3 boxes red at once, which I don't want. I want one at a time to be red.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox[] array = { box1, box2, box3 };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index = rnd.Next(array.Length);
        array[index].Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    }

    private void Box1_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        box1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
    }

    private void Box2_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        box2.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
    }

    private void Box3_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        box3.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question exactly?

Comment: You don't want a direct loop,  just have a method to set a box red again and call it from the constructor and each of the event listeners.

Comment: "When I put a loop..." It would be helpful if you posted ALL the code that causes this issue. And the "loop" is a major part of that code information. But, @Jason is correct. The code segment that sets a random `TextBox` red should be triggered in the `Listener` for reseting the `TextBox` back to White.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, you initialize a field `_textBoxes` to keep track of the `TextBox` instances in your view and a field for the random number generator to reuse it. Then we choose a random `TextBox`, since none has red background, yet.

```
private readonly Random _random;
private readonly TextBox[] _textBoxes;

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   _random = new Random();
   _textBoxes = new[] { box1, box2, box3 };

   // Set the initial TextBox background, currently none is red
   _textBoxes[_random.Next(_textBoxes.Length)].Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

In the [`MouseEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.MouseEnter);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) event that occurs whenever you enter the bounds of the source control, we select the next `TextBox` randomly, but ignore the current one, to prevent selecting it again. Instead of using the *Linq* methods [`Single`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=netcore-3.1) and [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1), you could also create a loop with `if` statements to achieve the same.

```
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // If the currently hovered TextBox has white background, ignore it
   if (((TextBox)sender).Background != Brushes.Red)
      return;

   // Exactly one TextBox has red background, get it
   var currentTextBox = _textBoxes.Single(textBox => textBox.Background == Brushes.Red);

   // Use the Where method to get a list of TextBoxes without the current one
   var nextTextBox = _textBoxes.Where(textBox => textBox != currentTextBox).ElementAt(_random.Next(_textBoxes.Length - 1));

   currentTextBox.Background = Brushes.White;
   nextTextBox.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Ensure that you use the [`MouseEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.MouseEnter);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.1) event with your `TextBox`es.

```
<TextBox x:Name="box1" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter"/>
```

However, instead of copy-pasting the event handler, you should rather create a reusable `Style` with an [`EventSetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventsetter?view=netcore-3.1) for `MouseEnter`. Omitting the name will make it an *implicit* style that is automatically applied to all text boxes within the container that it is defined in, as in this example a `StackPanel`.

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
         <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="OnMouseEnter"/>
      </Style>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <TextBox x:Name="box1"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="box2"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="box3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you only want to target specific text boxes, you can add a key to the style in the resource dictionary and assign it manually to a `TextBox`.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
   <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="OnMouseEnter"/>
</Style>
```

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle"/>
```

Comment: If only there was a way to apply an event to all textboxes.

Comment: @Andy Is that the reason for your vote? I did not introduce any styles or guessed the structure of the view apart from an _example_ that I reduced now, because that was not provided by the original poster and is not the core of the question as I understand it.

Comment: The onmousenter can be applied to all textboxes using an eventsetter. If you're going to show how to apply that event then showing a way that means someone has to paste code for every textbox is showing bad practice.

Comment: @Andy I have added samples for using a style and an event setter.